# Mapping MySQL Point Data Type with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-spatial

I have an existing MySQL database with a column in a table that has a "point" data type. The first thing I did was add the spatial dependency to our gradle build file via:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.4.2.Final'
```

I'm struggling to figure out exactly how to modify our mapping file (it's XML based, not using annotations) and the corresponding model to support loading this.

```
    <property name="pickupLocation" type="???">
        <column name="pickup_location" sql-type="???"/>
    </property>
```

From what I've gathered in the small subset of examples I can find online, I need it to end up in a: `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` data type in my model. That's essentially all I have on the model end. I would assume that sql-type should just be "point", but recognize that might be an inaccurate assumption. No matter what combination of types/sql-types I try, I generally end up with a deserialization error in an obscure stack trace that's not particularly helpful.

If it's relevant, I seeded the data in the table via: `SET pickup_location=POINT(18 -63)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `pickupLocation` is of type JTS Point, no `type` or `sql-type` should be necessary in the mapping file.

You may want to check that your application is actually using a Spatial Dialect (see the [manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial) for available dialects). It is the most common source for this type of problem.

In any case, the value `point` is correct for `sql-type`, and for `type` it should be `jts_geometry`.

Comment: For posterity, this proved accurate. Was able to solve it last evening. I had already converted to a Spatial dialect. The mapping file didn't need either a type or a sql-type as you said. I had to convert the Point to a org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point instead of the vividsolutions type, which was the bit that finally made it work. After turning on TRACE level debugging, it became a bit more clear. Thanks for the response.